# I heard that some old Haggadot originally had the passuk "ויבאנו אל המקום הזה" with an explanation. Where could I find this original text?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

Included in Haggada with drash
אֲרַמִּי אֹבֵד אָבִי, וַיֵּרֶד מִצְרַיְמָה, וַיָּגָר שָׁם בִּמְתֵי מְעָט; וַיְהִי-שָׁם, לְגוֹי גָּדוֹל עָצוּם וָרָב.
ו וַיָּרֵעוּ אֹתָנוּ הַמִּצְרִים, וַיְעַנּוּנוּ; וַיִּתְּנוּ עָלֵינוּ, עֲבֹדָה קָשָׁה.  ז וַנִּצְעַק, אֶל-יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵי אֲבֹתֵינוּ; וַיִּשְׁמַע יְהוָה אֶת-קֹלֵנוּ, וַיַּרְא אֶת-עָנְיֵנוּ וְאֶת-עֲמָלֵנוּ וְאֶת-לַחֲצֵנוּ.
ח וַיּוֹצִאֵנוּ יְהוָה, מִמִּצְרַיִם, בְּיָד חֲזָקָה וּבִזְרֹעַ נְטוּיָה, וּבְמֹרָא גָּדֹל--וּבְאֹתוֹת, וּבְמֹפְתִים.

Apparently was once included -- where can I get the text?
ט וַיְבִאֵנוּ, אֶל-הַמָּקוֹם הַזֶּה; וַיִּתֶּן-לָנוּ אֶת-הָאָרֶץ הַזֹּאת, אֶרֶץ זָבַת חָלָב וּדְבָשׁ

Also, is there an English translation available for this text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While some versions of the Haggada may have contained derashot on that verse (probably the one referred to by the Mishna, Pesachim 10:4), that section is no longer extant.

Rabbi Dr. David Mishlov authored his own reconstruction of that section [here](https://www.biu.ac.il/JH/Parasha/pesah/mis.html), following the style of the Haggada by bringing a verse or a derasha for each word of the verse (but of course not claiming to be based on an original version). It isn't translated into English, but since he gives the source for all of the places he brings, some of them might be available in translation elsewhere.

One sample to illustrate the style:

> וַיְבִאֵנוּ אֶל הַמָּקום הַזֶּה - זה בית המקדש, כמו שנאמר: לִהְיות עֵינֶיךָ פְתֻחות אֶל הַבַּיִת הַזֶּה לַיְלָה וָיום, אֶל הַמָּקום אֲשֶׁר אָמַרְתָּ 'יִהְיֶה שְׁמִי שָׁם', לִשְׁמועַ אֶל הַתְּפִלָּה אֲשֶׁר יִתְפַּלֵּל עַבְדְּךָ אֶל הַמָּקום הַזֶּה; וְשָׁמַעְתָּ אֶל תְּחִנַּת עַבְדְּךָ, וְעַמְּךָ יִשְׂרָאֵל, אֲשֶׁר יִתְפַּלְלוּ אֶל הַמָּקום הַזֶּה,
>   וְאַתָּה תִּשְׁמַע אֶל מְקום שִׁבְתְּךָ, אֶל הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְשָׁמַעְתָּ, וְסָלָחְתָּ
>
> דבר אחר : וַיְבִאֵנוּ אֶל הַמָּקום הַזֶּה - אתה מוצא ביעקב שראה אותו בנוי, וראה אותו חרב, וראה אותו בנוי, שנאמר: " וַיִּירָא וַיּאמַר: מַה נּורָא הַמָּקום הַזֶּה " - הרי בנוי,
>   " אֵין זֶה " - הרי חרב,  " כִּי אִם בֵּית אֱ-להִים, וְזֶה שַׁעַר הַשָּׁמָיִם " - הרי בנוי ומשוכלל לעתיד לבא.

According to [this site](https://www.biu.ac.il/JH/Parasha/pesah/cgi.html), the "Israeli Haggada" of Rabbi Menachem Mendel Kasher and the "Temple Haggada" of Rabbi Yisrael Ariel also contain such sections. However, I looked through the former, which is available [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/10541), but couldn't find that section anywhere, nor does he mention it in his introduction.